# I cannot use and import ApplicationContext in a Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I just started a Spring project. I can't use ApplicationContext. Can somebody help me ?

[image]

Comment: Hi There. Adding screenshots of code is discouraged. Post actual code.

Comment: You forgot the new keyword, maybe?

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you are new to Spring/Spring Boot. Looking at the tags of your question I assume, that you will want to build a backend application.

I suggest that try with a spring boot hello world tutorial: https://javabydeveloper.com/spring-boot-hello-world-example-rest/

Spring takes care of setting up the application context in the background, there is no need for doing that manually.

Comment: yes i am new to Spring/Spring boot:) actually i created maven project and i added spring context, spring core, spring beans dependencies. i'm watching the Spring courses, He does it like this and changes the java version to define or import ApplicationContext, but I dont have an import place.